# вывести значение массива по параметру

Tags: php

есть массив

```
$arr = array(
    'sort-asc'=> 'цена',
    'sort-new'=> 'новинки',
    'sort-Alfavit'=> 'по алфавиту',
);
```

где **sort-asc, sort-new, sort-Alfavit** - это параметры url **$_GET['sort']**, как достать элемент в зависимости от параметра в url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как то так, если я правильно вопрос понял

```
$arr = [
    'sort-asc'=> 'цена',
    'sort-new'=> 'новинки',
    'sort-Alfavit'=> 'по алфавиту',
];

$param = $_GET['sort']; // sort-new

echo $arr[$param]; // новинки
```

Comment: такой простой ответ отказывается, заработало =)

Comment: если данный ответ был полезен отметьте галочкой

Comment: "Вы можете принять ответ через 2 минуты" отмечу когда таймер пройдет